# Не работает локальная сеть в Linux Astra

Tags: linux, astra-linux, локальная-сеть

Столкнулся с проблемой по настройке сети в ОС Astra Linux SE (Smolensk) 1.6.
В локальной сети имеются компьютеры с Windows 7 без доступа к интернету,  настройку сети одного из них я перенес на Linux, но сеть не работает...
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: IP-адреса должны отличаться. Попробуйте последнее число поменять.

Comment: Ну я на компе с виндой сеть физически вырубил и вставил в линукс (провод переткнул) =) Поэтому конфликта не должно быть (да и другие айпи пробовал). Это просто для наглядности одинаковый ip написал

Comment: Что за tun и откуда метрика 100?

Comment: Сам не знаю что это... Вручную я ничего не прописывал

Comment: а что именно «не работает»? `$ ping -c 3 10.18.6.49` работает? `$ ping -c 3 10.18.6.118` работает?  `$ ping -c 3 8.8.8.8` работает? если только последняя команда «не работает», то вопрос: а она должна в вашей сети работать? // ну и вы всё-таки разберитесь, что там у вас за туннель, и зачем он нужен (при неработающей, как вы утверждаете, сети).

Comment: Сегодня проверить не смогу. Сеть на винде пускает как на локальные ресурсы, так и на "межлокальные" (с другими организациями с такой же "политикой" защиты) =) Видимо проблема в зашифрованном трафике через вип нет координаторы...

Comment: ping 10.18.6.49 - ответы приходят,

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в неправильной настройке доступа к криптомаршрутизатору (со стороны админов сети). С настройкой локальной сети всё было в норме.

Comment: рубиконы они такие